# find columns meeting a condition in r

Tags: r, matrix, apply, sapply

I am trying to get unique column names meeting a certain condition. For example, with this matrix `M`, I am trying to get the unique column having smaller than 5. From the matrix, my desiring outcome is a vector `(a,b,c)` - `a` from the first row, `b` from the second row, `b` from the thrid row `c` from the fifth row.

```
set.seed(1234)
M = matrix(sample(20,20), ncol=4)

   M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3   10    7    9
[2,]   12    1    5   17
[3,]   11    4   20   16
[4,]   18    8   15   19
[5,]   14    6    2   13

colnames(M) = letters[1:4]
```

Comment: `colnames(M)[colSums(M < 5) > 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility using `base-R` can be as

```
M[,colSums(M<5)>0]

#       a  b  c
# [1,]  3 10  7
# [2,] 12  1  5
# [3,] 11  4 20
# [4,] 18  8 15
# [5,] 14  6  2
```

If OP wants to know just the names of columns meeting criteria then solution can be as:

```
colnames(M[,colSums(M<5)>0])
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```